# preg_match Issue with "or", "and" in PHP

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I get the URL information from a input wiht POST Method.

Probable URLs:

- ex.1: http://host.com
- ex.2: http://www.host.com
- ex.3: www.host.com
- ex.4: host.com

I want to, the url not to begin `"http://www."` **or** `"www."` **also** *only begin* `"http://"`. I used that code block but it is not success.

```
preg_match(("/(^http:\/\/www\.)|(^www\.)/")), $url_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex can be simplified somewhat:

```
preg_match("/^http://(?!www\.)/", $url_data);
```

This will look for `http://` at the beginning of the string *not followed by (`?!`)* `www.`. [Here's an example on Regexpal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=http%3A%2F%2F%28%3F!www%5C.%29&input=http%3A%2F%2Fhost.com%0Ahttp%3A%2F%2Fwww.host.com%0Awww.host.com%0Ahost.com).

Comment: Thanks @Bojangles Well, how can i denied the all subs? In other words, like:

 - `http://host.com "ONLY THIS PASS"`
   
 - `http://'anything.'host.com "FAIL"`
   
example:

 - `http://www.host.com "FAIL"`
 - `http://sub.host.com "FAIL"`

Answer (score 0):

```
^http:\/\/(?!www\.).*$
```

should do it.

deme here : http://regex101.com/r/bA1rR4

**update**

if you dont want to have any subdomain.

use this :

```
^http:\/\/(?!www\.)\w+\.\w+$
```

demo here : http://regex101.com/r/jY0aP6

**second update**

```
^http:\/\/(?!www\.)\w+\.\w+(?:\/.*)?$
```

http://regex101.com/r/vO5xV4

allowing for anything after extension

Comment: Thanks @aelor. Well, how can i denied the all subs? In other words, like:

 - `http://host.com "ONLY THIS PASS"`
   
 - `http://'anything.'host.com "FAIL"`
   
example:

 - `http://www.host.com "FAIL"`
 - `http://sub.host.com "FAIL"`

Comment: thanks for update. I was try that regex all subdomains denied, perfect, but i have a problem; "http://host.com/" is "FAIL". If I add anything after .com (.org, .net or any extension etc.) it is fail. I don't want this.

I want;

- denied all sub domains and www
- only pass which one start http://
- and if is there anything after the extension is pass. like this http://host.com/'anything'

Comment: Thanks a lot @aelor, because you are very helpfully person. I change my regex according to your suggestions. Finally, my regex final pattern is "http://regex101.com/r/rR3zO2" So my last request How can I denied "http://host.com" Look at the link please, first five url must be denied and 7.8.9.10.11.12.13 links only pass, look at link for easily understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative lookahead regular expression here. Expression which begin with `"http://"` will also satisfy expression not to start with `"www."`.

Finally you have 2 conditions to meet
1. Begin with `"http://"` 
2. Not to begin with `"http://www."`

And following preg_match function will do the trick:

```
preg_match("^http:\/\/(?!www\.).*$", $url_data);
```